# SSH session and ClientAlive problem

Tags: ssh, session

I have a question about ssh configuration. In a test machine I've set:

```
# TCPKeepAlive yes
Protocol 2 
ClientAliveInterval 60 
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

And if I wait a minute, session does not close.

I've checked sshd_config man page and I didn't find more options to change.

Comment: I've tried with 0, 1 and 2 and it does not work :(

Comment: What are you doing on the client side to prevent it from responding to the client alive messages?

Comment: Good question. I've started ssh session and I'm waiting 1 minute in order to close it automatically. I don't know if it is the best way to reproduce it. I don't do any action, only waiting.

Comment: I did finally find some documentation that says you interpreted the use of 0 correctly. The strange thing is that it is not mentioned in the man page not a couple other primary doc locations. Also, it's not working for you. Hopefully someone with more insight will come along.

Comment: to validate, you need to make sure that your client is actually, truly idle, and not sending *any* data over the encrypted channel.

Comment: @TimKennedy yes, with Putty works fine, but with MobaXterm not. I think Moba sends data in background I have to go deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClientAliveInterval` is the number of seconds after which, if no data has passed the encrypted channel, the server will send a keepalive message.

`ClientAliveCountMax` is the maximum number of keepalive messages the server will send to the client, *without receiving a response*, before it disconnects the client.

---

`ClientAliveInterval` defaults to `0` which indicates that these keepalive messages will not be sent at all.  Yours is set to `60`, which would indicate you want to close idle sessions after 1 minute of inactivity.

However, your `ClientAliveCountMax` is set to `0`, which (to my understanding) would disable the limit.  Try setting this to `1`.  That should tell `sshd` that it should close idle sessions after a single iteration of 60 seconds idle.

---

If you want to close the connection after 10 idle minutes, you could set:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 10
```

Comment: I did a test and I've could check that if I set these parameters and I connect using Putty session closes in 10 minutes, but if I use other ssh client, for example MobaXterm it does not work. Thanks, it works on Putty :)

Comment: there's a keepalive checkbox in moba, in the settings menu, on the ssh tab.  otherwise, maybe it's something with the sftp browser that opens on the side.